# Within the set of signed integers representable by a bit string of length n, are any two elements equivalent to each other mod 2^n?

Tags: computer-architecture, binary, modular-arithmetic

Donald Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1 Fascicle 1* contains the following exercise:

> If $\alpha$ is any string of 0s and 1s, let $\operatorname{s}(\alpha)$ and $\operatorname{u}(\alpha)$ be the integers that it represents when regarded as a signed or unsinged binary number. Prove that, if $x$ is any integer, we have:
> $$
> x={s}(\alpha) \text{ if and only if } x\equiv {u}(\alpha)\bmod 2^n \text{ and} -2^{n-1} \le x \lt 2^{n-1} \text{ where } n \text{ is the length of } \alpha
> $$

The solution provided is:

> If $-2^{n-1} \le x \lt 2^{n-1}$, then $-2^n \le x-{s}(\alpha) \le 2^n$; hence $x \neq {s}(\alpha)$ implies  $x \not\equiv {s}(\alpha)\bmod 2^n$.
>
> But ${s}(\alpha)={u}(\alpha) - 2^n\equiv {u}(\alpha)\bmod 2^n$ when $\alpha$ begins with 1.

I am confused about the last statement in the first line of the solution (i.e. if $x$ is not equal to ${s}(\alpha)$ , then $x$ is also not equivalent to ${s}(\alpha)$ under modulus $ 2^n$). To me that seems to imply that the answer to the title of this post is "no". But isn't $x=1$, ${s}(\alpha)=-1$ a simple counter example that works for any length bit string? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If $s(\alpha)=-1$, then $s(\alpha)\equiv_{2^n}2^n-1\not\equiv_{2^n}1$ for any $n>1$.

Another argument you may find compelling: if $a \equiv_m b$, then $a-b$ is a multiple of $m$. Since $x-s(\alpha)=1-(-1)=2$ is prime, $x$ and $s(\alpha)$ can only be equivalent mod 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Daniel. Turns out what I was missing was a basic understanding of how modular arithmetic works for negative numbers lol.